# Run multiple commands and get no output if anyone fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a set of three `commands`, `command1`, `command2`, and `command3`, which don't produce any output if they fail. I want to run these commands together using `command1 && command2 && command3`, and only display output if all of the commands succeed. However, if any of the commands fail, I don't want to see any output at all. The problem with using `&&` is that if `command1` **succeeds** and `command2` **fails**, I still get **the output of command1**, but I want to see no output in this case

Comment: For stdout `x1=$(command1) && x2=$(command2) && x3=$(command3) && printf '%s\n' "$x1" "$x2" "$x3"` -- also for stderr if you're okay merging it with stdout using `2>&1` inside each `$( )`. If you want stderr conditional but separate from stdout it's harder, and if any of the programs directly uses `/dev/tty` or similar you'll have to resort to something like `expect` or `script`.

Comment: Collect the output of each command into a file. In the end, print the file if you come to the conclusion that all commands worked. Having said this, your definition of _command failure_ is a bit unclear. First you write that you recognize a failing command by the fact that no output is produced. Then (by using `&&`) you indicate that a failing command can be recognized by testing its exit code. Even more, when you talk about command output, you don't say whether you are refering to stdout, or stderr, or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shall just do the work

```
output=$(command1 && command2 && command3) && echo "$output"
```

Comment: This. Maybe also add stderr redirection if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
( command1 && command2 && command3 ) > out.tmp 2>&1 && cat out.tmp
rm -f out.tmp
```

Comment: Maybe: Use `temp=$(mktemp)` as first line and replace `out.tmp` by `$temp`.